# My SQL table is too big: retrieving data via paging/segmenting the result?

Tags: sql, algorithm, design-patterns

**This is a design/algorithm question.**
Here's the outline of my scenario:

- I have a large table (say, 5 mil. rows) of data which I'll call **Cars**
- Then I have an application, which performs a `SELECT *` on this **Cars** table, taking all the data and packaging it into a single data file (which is then uploaded somewhere.)
- This data file generated by my application represents a snapshot, what the table looked like at an instant in time.
- The table **Cars**, however, is updated sporadically by another process, regardless of whether the application is currently generating a package from the table or not. (There currently is no synchronization.)

**My problem**:

This table **Cars** is becoming too big to do a single `SELECT *` against. When my application retrieves all this data at once, it quickly overwhelms the memory capacity for my machine (let's say, 2GB.) Also, simply performing chained `SELECT`s with LIMIT or OFFSET fails the condition of synchronization: the table is frequently updated and I can't have the data change between SELECT calls.

**What I'm looking for**:

A way to pull the entirety of this table into an application whose memory capacity is smaller than the data, assuming the data size could approach infinity. Particularly, how do I achieve a pagination/segmented effect for my SQL selects? i.e. Make recurring calls with a page number to retrieve the next segment of data. The ideal solution allows for scalability in data size.

(For the sake of simplifying my scenario, we can assume that when given a segment of data, the application can process/write it then free up the memory used before requesting the next segment.)

Any suggestions you may be able to provide would be most helpful. Thanks!

EDIT: By request, my implementation uses C#.NET 4.0 & MSSQL 2008.

EDIT #2: ***This is not a SQL command question***. This is design-pattern related question: what is the strategy to perform paginated SELECTs against a large table? (Especially when said table receives consistent updates.)

Comment: First of all: **NEVER EVER** use `SELECT *` in a production environment - no matter what.

Comment: Second: **which database** and what version are you talking about?? SQL is just the Structured Query Language used by many database systems - that doesn't help us possibly help you at all..... we need to know which database product you're using

Comment: @marc_s: You should really explain why if you make such an assertion. Generally I agree but there are situations where `select *` is valid, for example when you are reading the metadata of the dbreader to use the results.

Comment: @PaulCreasey: I think the *why not use `SELECT *` in production code* question is **so well documented** in so many blogs, articles etc. that I shouldn't have to repeat that every time..... if you [must see another blog post - let it be this one by Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/10/bad-habits-to-kick-using-select-omitting-the-column-list)

Comment: Whoa, whoa, ok. It was meant to be a simplistic example. I get it. I should probably name my columns explicitly. To answer your other question though, MSSQL 2008 is the DB of choice here.

Comment: I am still unclear as to what you are trying to achieve exactly. All I can think of is that you could setup a stored procedure that, on insert and update, updates your smaller memory environment with just the data you need. That would also keep that environment up to date if anything changes. Almost like a restricted version of database replication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a "snapshot" effect you have to copy the data into holding table where it will not get updated.  You can accomplish some nice things with various types of change-tracking, but that's not what you stated you wanted.  If you need a snapshot of the exact table state then take the snapshot and write it to a seperate table and use the limit and offset (or whatever) to create pages.

And at 5 million rows, I think it is likely the design requirement that might need to be modified...if you have 2000 clients all taking 5 million-row snapshots you are going to start having some size issues if you don't watch out.

Comment: This is definitely more along the lines of the kind of answer I was looking for. Indeed, 5 million row selects multiplied out does represent a bottleneck... luckily, the purpose of this select is more of a 'full backup' that is performed quite infrequently. To handle more incremental changes in the table, we have another process that creates small changeset packages instead.

Thanks for your response!

Answer (score 1):

What database are you using? In MySQL for example the following would select 20 rows beginning from row 40 but this is mysql-only clause (edit: it seems Postgres also allows this)

```
 select * from cars limit 20 offset 40
```

Answer (score 0):

You should provide details of the format of the resultant data file. Depending on the format this could be possible directly in your database, with no app code involved eg for mysql:

```
SELECT * INTO OUTFILE "c:/mydata.csv"
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY "\n"
FROM my_table;
```

For oracle there would be export, for sqlserver/sybase it would be BCP, etc.

Or alternatively achievable by streaming the data, without holding it all in memory, this would vary depending on the app language.

In terms of paging, the easy option is to just use the limit clause (if mysql) or the equivelent in whatever rdbms you are using, but this is a last resort:

```
select * from myTable order by ID LIMIT 0,1000
select * from myTable order by ID LIMIT 1000,1000
select * from myTable order by ID LIMIT 2000,1000
...
```

This selects the data in 1000 row chunks.

Comment: Thanks for the response; unfortunately when I take that data into my application, I do some extra processing on it, then remap the rows into JSON objects, one per line, so direct CSV export won't help me here. What are the alternatives? I'm using C#.NET 4.0 & MSSQL 2008. That programmatic selecting by LIMIT was my intuitive stab at pagination as well, but was hoping for a more refined pattern.

Comment: @Dave - If you are massaging the data after you retrieve then I recommend you create a view of the data and implement that data manipulation in the view. If you make the view match exactly to the desired output then you can use Paul's solution against this view instead of the table.

Comment: Oh, not a bad idea.

But it's safe to say we do a little beyond massaging the data; it gets chopped up, constructed into list of data transfer objects, checked/pruned programmatically, then serialized into a large JSON data file.

All the same, it gives for an interesting idea... I could use the aforementioned OUTFILE, FTP it over to my application, open a file stream and read only parts at a time, and process my data in chunks. I've also heard that a SqlDataReader in .NET would provided the unbuffered streaming of this same data without the file transfer stuff... something I'm looking into.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this post on using limit and offset to create paginated results from your sql query.

http://www.petefreitag.com/item/451.cfm

You would have to first:

```
SELECT * from Cars Limit 10
```

and then

```
SELECT * from Cars limit 10 offset 10
```

And so on. You will have to figure out the best pagination for this.

Comment: Thanks; I'm aware of the LIMIT and OFFSET options, but neither are what I'm asking for. I'm looking for a strategy for achieving this pagination, one that may involve these options, with the caveat that the table is being consistently updated. If an update were to occur between these SELECTs, and before the entire table was selected, it would fail my objective. (See my 'snapshot' condition)

Comment: You wouldn't fail your objective if you had some sort of self incrementing id to order by. You will probably need a local record of the last processed id in case you failed to retrieve part of the data at some point.

Comment: If *any* content in the table changes during the SELECTs, its considered a failure (doesn't meet my requirements), because its no longer a snapshot due to a mid-flight change in the data. Sure, I can keep track of IDs, but IDs can be added, removed, or their corresponding data modified, which doesn't help me. This condition implies I need some sort of synchronization mechanism, hence, design related question.